# Accessing files with permissions through live cd of ubuntu for backing up the entire files of a previous installation

Tags: permissions

Hi all iam having an ubuntu istallation on my laptop which happens to be not working, i need to back up my data as the ubuntu is not booting up. but when i tried to back up data  by connecting the hard drive through hard disk enclosure on a different pc though live usb feature of ubuntu , there are some files of my personal data which cannot be accessed and says i do not have permissions to use, read or open. Can anyone please provide me a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use the command

```
sudo cp -r /path/to/filestobackup /media/drive/pathtobackupfolder
```

That will gives you sudo rights, and should allow you to copy. If you are only copying your home are (`/home/<USER>`) then it should be fine.